# Config files in Assets but still error in Play Mode

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

I loaded my config files in Assets folder. When I am in Edit Mode this files are visible. But when I hit Play Mode I get an error below. And when I get back into Edit Mode the config files are seen by firebase again.

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of your log (it's truncated, so I can't see the whole thing) it looks like you have your google-services.json file included. Just double check to make sure that it appears in your assets directory like so:
[image: google-services.json]

Putting it under Data is my own personal style and isn't necessary. With that being said, you may want to try moving it into the root of your Assets directory. Especially if it was under a [special folder](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpecialFolders.html) (and commenting which special folder below).

Similarly, ensure that you're on the [latest Firebase plugin](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/unity).

Before I go forward with any more troubleshooting steps, also make sure that you're not using a plugin that conditionally removes some assets from a build for localization or cross compilation reasons. If you are, ensure that it's not doing something like moving your google-services.json file to an [excluded directory](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpecialFolders.html) (ex: with a directory that ends in `~`).

It can be useful to just re-download your google-services.json file just in case it's been edited in any strange ways. You can do this by going to project settings:
[image: project settings]

And clicking the button with the text "google-services.json" on it:
[image]

Finally, I'd recommend just trying to force resolve the play services provider from the Unity editor if none of the above helps:
[image]

If none of the above works or you think you've found a bug in the Firebase plugin, feel free to reach out to support as well: https://firebase.google.com/support

I hope any of this helps!

--Patrick

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I tried all of that but the problem stayed. I already contacted Firebase support and they said that it's indeed some king of bug.